# Ajax loader gif not working in ie and chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to show a gif loader using ajax, on the click of submit button on the page. The loader is showing in firefox, but I cannot see it in IE and Chrome. When I remove `async: false` it works fine on all browsers, but I want it to be synchronous. 
Here is my code for the loader:

```
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false, async: false });
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $('#imgloader').removeClass('loading').addClass('loading');
        $('#imgloader').show();
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        $('#imgloader').removeClass('loading');
        $('#imgloader').hide();
    });
```

Comment: Why do you want to do a synchronous request instead of an asynchronous one ?

Answer (score 0):

From the JQuery documentation :

> Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.

So basically, the browser is busy with the synchronous request and won't do anything before it's finished

If you really want to do a synchronous request, you need to explicitly add the class to your div **before** sending the request

Comment: How to add class? I dint get it can you please give an example

Comment: @sumedha Instead of registering a callback with $.ajaxStart and $.ajaxAfter, call the two lines of each functions before and after doing the request

Comment: how? I still dint get it. Sorry I am completely new to ajax, this is the first time I am using it

Comment: @sumedha If you're new t ajax and don't understand the implications of doing a synchronous request instead of an asynchronous one, you should use asynchronous request. It's the standard way and it'll be a lot easier